# Removing unused item from RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-firestore

I want to show the hospitals near me and also in firestore.So I gave condition that if the hospital near to me within radius of 1 km are equal to those hospital in my firestore data will show in the RecyclerView. Its working that its showing as per condition but if their is four hospital near me and among those One is in my firestore then its showing one hospital name and also showing other three items in RecyclerView as blank which is not in the firestore.

**Code of RecyclerView Adapter**

```
public class HospitalAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<HospitalAdapter.MyViewHolder> {
        ArrayList<HospitalData> hospitalDataList;
        Context context;
        private int lastPosition = -1;
        private FirebaseFirestore fStore;
    
        public HospitalAdapter(ArrayList<HospitalData> hospitalDataList, Context context) {
            this.hospitalDataList = hospitalDataList;
            this.context = context;
        }
    
        @NonNull
        @Override
        public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
            View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext())
                    .inflate(R.layout.hospital_list_view, viewGroup, false);
    
            return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
    
        }
    
    
        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder viewHolder, final int i) {
            final HospitalData data = hospitalDataList.get(i);
    
            fStore= FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
            Query query=fStore.collection("Hospital");
            query.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                    if(task.isSuccessful()){
                        for(QueryDocumentSnapshot queryDocumentSnapshot: Objects.requireNonNull(task.getResult())){
                            if(queryDocumentSnapshot.getString("Name").equals(data.hospitalName)){
    
                                viewHolder.name.setText(data.hospitalName);
                                viewHolder.distance.setText(data.distance + " Km");
                                viewHolder.rating.setText(data.rating);
    
                                setAnimation(viewHolder.parent, i);
                                viewHolder.parent.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onClick(View view) {
                                        Intent intent = new Intent(context, HospitalDepartment.class);
                                        intent.putExtra("hospitalName", data.hospitalName);
                                        intent.putExtra("Latitude",String.valueOf(data.lat));
                                        intent.putExtra("Longitude",String.valueOf(data.lon));
                                        context.startActivity(intent);
                                    }
                                });
    
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
    
    
    
        }
    
        private void setAnimation(View viewToAnimate, int position) {
            // If the bound view wasn't previously displayed on screen, it's animated
            if (position > lastPosition) {
                Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, android.R.anim.slide_in_left);
                viewToAnimate.startAnimation(animation);
                lastPosition = position;
            }
        }
    
        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return hospitalDataList.size();
        }
    
        static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
            TextView name, distance, rating;
            ConstraintLayout parent;
    
            public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
                super(itemView);
                parent = itemView.findViewById(R.id.parent);
                name = itemView.findViewById(R.id.hName);
                distance = itemView.findViewById(R.id.hDistance);
                rating = itemView.findViewById(R.id.hRating);
            }
        }
```

[Screen Shots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/axM1Z.png)

Comment: What are your issues? could you give more details?

Comment: Use this    hospitalDataList.remove(position);
                        notifyDataSetChanged();  to remove from postion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't fetch `Hospitals` list every time on `BindViewHolder`, it is a bad practice, instead fetch the `hospitals` from `firestore` and filter the data prior to setting data to adapter like below

```
    ArrayList<HospitalData> hospitalDataList = new ArrayList<>();//fill this with local data
    Query query=fStore.collection("Hospital");
    query.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
       @Override
       public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
           if(task.isSuccessful()){
              ArrayList<QueryDocumentSnapshot> fireStoreData = task.getResult();
               for(HospitalData data: hospitalDataList){
                   for(QueryDocumentSnapshot fireData: fireStoreData){
                         if(queryDocumentSnapshot.getString("Name").equals(list.get(finalI1).name)){
                                HospitalData data = new HospitalData(list.get(finalI1).name, numberFormat.format(distanceKilometer), list.get(finalI1).rating.toString() + "/5.0", true,list.get(finalI1).latitude,list.get(finalI1).longitude);
                                hospitalDataList.add(data);
                         }
                    }
               }
               hospitalAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
           }
       }               
  });
```

Comment: I have used this method but problem is 'HospitalData data = new HospitalData(list.get(finalI1).name, numberFormat.format(distanceKilometer), list.get(finalI1).rating.toString() + "/5.0", true,list.get(finalI1).latitude,list.get(finalI1).longitude);                 hospitalDataList.add(data);' this line is not able to store the data. Writing code in below comment

Comment: I have updated the answer, `notiffyDataSetChanged` should be inside `onComplete`

Comment: Thank you very much sir.You are correct.Problem solved.

Comment: Glad I could help, do accept the answer if you think solution worked

Answer (score 1):

The item count of a recycler view is determined by the `getItemCount()` method. So, to solve your problem, the simplest I can think of is have a member variable that holds the size of the recycler view in your adapter class. And return that in `getItemCount()` method. Now you are going to update this size member variable in your `onComplete()` method according to the size of the result list received. After that, call `notifyDataSetChanged()` to update your recycler view accordingly.

Now while this may solve your problem, I think you do not have any need to pass the ArrayList with all hospital data to your adapter since you are not displaying all of them anyway. I would suggest you to move the fetch operation of FireStore data to your activity. So fetch the data, compare it with your all HospitalData list and create another List having only the Hospitals that match and feed this particular List to your recycler view.

Comment: I have provided the code in answer please check. Still having problem

Answer (score 0):

in hospital_list_view.xml setVisibility to GONE to parent layout

Answer (score 0):

```
    RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
            HospitalAdapter hospitalAdapter = new HospitalAdapter((ArrayList<HospitalData>) hospitalDataList, HospitalListActivity.this);
            RecyclerView.LayoutManager manager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(manager);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(hospitalAdapter);   
    
    
     fStore= FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
                    Query query=fStore.collection("Hospital");
                    final int finalI1 = i;
                    query.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                            if(task.isSuccessful()){
                                for(QueryDocumentSnapshot queryDocumentSnapshot: Objects.requireNonNull(task.getResult())){
                                    if(queryDocumentSnapshot.getString("Name").equals(list.get(finalI1).name)){
                                        HospitalData data = new HospitalData(list.get(finalI1).name, numberFormat.format(distanceKilometer), list.get(finalI1).rating.toString() + "/5.0", true,list.get(finalI1).latitude,list.get(finalI1).longitude);
                                        hospitalDataList.add(data);
        
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    });
hospitalAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Problem is in `hospitalDataList.add(data);` not storing data and sending to adapter.Inside the condition `if(queryDocumentSnapshot.getString("Name").equals(list.get(finalI1).name))` when I printing `list.get(finalI1).name)` in log then its printing corectly but problem is not storing data and sending to adapter.

Comment: move your call to `notifyDataSetChanged()` inside the if block of `onComplete()` method. it should go in the last line of the if block.